# Selection of particular text in two lines with different scenarios

Tags: vba, ms-word, selection

I had been in a situation in which I need to select particular text in two lines. I had been doing this by the following code:

```
Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
```

But the above code is not applicable to all four following scenarios. I'm in search of code which would output selection of first line and second line till 'comma'. I need code as simple as possible, kindly help.

**Scenario 1**

Infraestructura Energetica Nova SAB De CV

IENOVA* MM, Buy

**Scenario 2**

Infraestructura Energetica Nova SAB De CV

IENOVA13 MM, Sell

**Scenario 3**

Infraestructura Energetica Nova SAB De CV

IENOVA* MM

**Scenario 4 Edited**

Nova SAB

IENOVA MM

**Illustration with Picture:**

[image]

Comment: Scenario 3 and Scenario 4 don't have any comma's is this correct?

Comment: yes 4th has no comma. and sorry for late reply.. plus one thing more to add, the letters " MM" are not always the same it may be ' TI' for turkey ' RO' for Romania, so on. but it surly two letters word with upper case.

Comment: no  problems, I'll edit my answer which should cover this.

Comment: To clarify, is the format of your scenarios above the only format this code will be following?

Comment: Format is somehow same

Comment: I've edited my answer to cater for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works with the two paragraphs as separate ranges. The first paragraph is picked up unaltered and used as the starting point for getting the second paragraph.

Using the `Instr` function, it determines whether a comma is present - `Instr` returns 0 if there is none, otherwise a positive number.

If there is no comma, the paragraph mark is cut off. It's not clear whether you want this Chr(13), if you do, just comment out that line and the paragraph is picked up with no changes.

If there is a comma, the Range is collapsed to its starting point, then extended to the position of the comma, minus 1 (leaves out the comma).

The two strings are then concatenated for debug.print. And then the endpoint of the first Range is extended to the end point of the second Range, so that you have one Range (if that's what you need - that's not clear).

```
Sub SelectInfo()
    Dim rngLine1 As Word.Range
    Dim rngLine2 As Word.Range
    Dim isComma As Long

    Set rngLine1 = Selection.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range
    Set rngLine2 = rngLine1.Duplicate
    rngLine2.Collapse (wdCollapseEnd)
    Set rngLine2 = rngLine2.Paragraphs(1).Range

    isComma = InStr(rngLine2.Text, ",")
    If isComma = 0 Then
        'No comma, assume we don't want the last paragraph mark...
        rngLine2.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
    Else
        rngLine2.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        rngLine2.MoveEnd wdCharacter, isComma - 1
    End If

    Debug.Print rngLine1.Text & rngLine2.Text
    'Get a single Range instead of the string:
    rngLine1.End = rngLine2.End
End Sub
```

Comment: You are working in ranges this is great. but in my case I need to copy the selected text and then paste it to excel file in two rows. so please can you elaborate more about copy/paste of range.text. Please consider the paragraph mark in first line which will help me in pasting.

Comment: The paragraph mark from the first line is included automatically. You don't mention copy/paste in your question, but that's simple enough: `rngLIne1.Copy` just before `End Sub`. Or if you prefer selection, then `rngLine1.Select : Selection.Copy`. The two should work the same.

Comment: your answer serves well. However you are using `.Range`, the code get lengthy as compare to `Selection.` method (Mention in another answer). I'm wondering if it effects the speed of execution?

Comment: @IbneAshiq In general, working with `Range` objects is faster than working using `Selection` - the screen doesn't have to update (and it's quieter to look at). There are certainly numerous ways to go about this. I chose this one because it's clear what's going on, reasonably efficient in execution and simple to maintain, in case requirements would change. The other suggestion repeats, internally, moving the end until the target character is found. This is like holding the Shift key and pressing Right-Arrow numerous times...

Comment: Its off topic but I cannot find another way to communicate. I had learned that you are Author of a book called 'Office VBA Macros You Can Use Today'. I cannot afford to buy the book but my curiousity led me to ask about it. Does it had a free pdf version? can I have it free :)

Comment: @IbneAshiq Co-author, only, and as far as I know, there's no free version. But there are pay-to-use on-line versions, I believe, that might be less expensive than the entire book (which is at least 10 years old BTW). Contact the publisher (Bill Jelen) for more information.

Comment: Till then I can ask Questions from stackoverflow, I have had another Problem to solve, I'm sure you have answer for that too,
https://stackoverflow.com/q/50962517/6236294

Answer (score 1):

Taking your question literally:

> ...I'm in search of code which would output selection of first line and second line till 'comma'.

You can make an adjustment to the 2nd line of your code as follows;

```
Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
Selection.MoveEndUntil ",", wdForward
```

What this does is moves the end of the selection forward until it finds ",".

If however, per your 'Scenarios', some of the selections may not contain a comma, the following will work:

Sub SelectionTest()

```
Dim mySel As String

With Selection
    .Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
        mySel = Selection
            If InStr(1, mySel, ",") Then
                .MoveEndUntil ",", wdForward
            Else
                .Extend "M"
                .Extend "M"
            End If

End With
```

End Sub

What this does is selects the paragraph, sets the string to the variable mySel and using the InStr function tests if the string contains a comma, if it does, it executes the same code as above, but if there is no comma, it extends the selection until the character "M" (upper case M) and then extends the selection again to the next "M".

As indicated in your comment the "MM" part of your text is a variable so:

```
Sub SelectionTest()

    Dim mySel As String

        With Selection
             .Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
             .MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
              mySel = Selection
                 If InStr(1, mySel, ",") Then
                     .Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
                     .MoveEndUntil ","
                 Else: Exit Sub
                 End If
        End With
End Sub
```

What this does is selects the first paragraph and then extends the selection to the end of the 2nd line, sets selected text to the variable `mySel` and using the `InStr` function tests if the string contains a comma, if it does, it executes the same code as above, but if there is no comma, it keeps the 2 lines selected and that's it.

This keeps code shorter rather than having an `ElseIf` statement for each Country ("MM", "RO", "TI" etc) but does rely on no text after the Country code. Otherwise follow the previous part of the answer and repeat the `ElseIf` for each Country variable.

I tested this on all of your scenarios (by copy/pasting your scenario paragraphs into word) and each one resulted the same as your 'target selection' as long as the cursor was at the start of the required paragraph when the code was run.

Alternatively you can omit the part specifying the comma and just use (perhaps adjust as required and put this within an if statement to allow for your variables):

```
With Selection
    .Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
    .Extend "M"
    .Extend "M"
End With
```

These codes will work based on what you've asked and provided in your question but may not be the most universal code in it's current form.

There is some more info on the functions and methods used in the below links:

- [Selection.MoveEndUntil](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/selection-moveenduntil-method-word)
- [Selection.Extend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/selection-extend-method-word)
- [InStr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instr-function)
- [Selection.MoveDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/selection-movedown-method-word)

Comment: Dear you are in right path.. but prolem is when the first line got less text than second line the selection changes as both lines are variable too. kindly take this into account. I have edited this in my question's 4th scenario.