# Delete all Paragraph Marks except bullets, using Range

Tags: vba, range, ms-word, bulletedlist, paragraph-marker

I need to delete all paragraph marks of `ActiveDocument` except:

1. The one which is having **Bold-Font** after. (Example is in picture, attached)
2. Bullet-Point paragraph marks.

By using `Ranges` I came up with the following Code. It works well, but it is not detecting the bullet points. What should I do? I am beginner to use `Ranges`.

```
Sub PARAGRAPHSmark()
Dim PARA As Range
Dim p   As Range
Set PARA = ActiveDocument.Range
PARA.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
Do
Set p = PARA.Duplicate
p.Find.Execute "^13"
 PARA.Start = p.End
If p.Find.Found Then
    p.MoveEnd wdCharacter, 1
    If p.Bold = False Then
    p.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1

    ' This `If` condition is not detecting bullet when actually its  there.
       If p.ListFormat.ListType = wdListListNumOnly Or p.ListFormat.ListType = wdListSimpleNumbering Or p.ListFormat.ListType = wdListBullet Then

        Else
        p.Delete
        p.InsertAfter " "
        End If
    Else
    End If
Else
Exit Do
End If
Loop

End Sub
```

**Illustration:**
[image]

Comment: Does the following work: Ctrl+H (Replace dialog). Find text: ^p then click "more", then "Format"; choose Font and select Bold. Leave Replace empty. Execute ReplaceAll. If that works, just record it in a macro...

Comment: Yes, Forward=False is what you use to search backwards.